# What is the value of $ (a+b) $ where $ a\log_{1971}3 + b\log_{1971}{73} = 2012 $

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

I have two integers which are a and b .  They satisfy the following equation which is  $ a\log_{1971}3 + b\log_{1971}{73} = 2012  $ . I want to know the value of   $ (a+b) $ .

I have tried to solve this question and got the following equation . Then I cant proceed .

$ 1971^{2012} = 3^a73^b $

What can I do ?

Comment: yeah it should be 3 instead of 2012 or that !

Comment: Note that $1971=3^3\cdot 73$.

Comment: @AtulGangwar Good thing we asked: it turns out it should have been 2012 instead of 3.

Comment: In case it is not a typo, I suspect that the teacher puts this question every year on the paper where the year is perhaps irrelevant to the answer of $a+b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $1971=3^3\cdot73$.  Since $1971$ is raised to the $2012^{th}$ power, we can easily see what $a$ and $b$ are.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this to find $a,b$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

It would give $b=2012,a=2012*3$